# exe file can't start because libgomp_64-1.dll is missing (Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, compiler-errors

I've compiled a project on my computer Windows 7 with eclipse. It works well on my computer. However, it does not work when I put the exe file in another computer and gives a error "**The program can't start because libgomp_64-1.dll is missing. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem** ".

Even if I compile in statically linking with -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++, it seems no any change. Do someone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to properly deploy your application **including all dependencies**. *libgomp_64-1.dll* is very likely not the only dependency. Create an installer, or at least ship all files in a ZIP archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall MinGW, or copy the missing `dll` to the folder from where your `exe` is being called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there any other solution? Because I have to give others to use the program, It is not a good idea to ask them to install  some other files. @Marcelo Vinícius

Comment: If you depend on this dll to run your program, the others are going to need it too. So you must properly static link (as you mentioned) the libraries (nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811720/c-how-to-compile-dll-in-a-exe)), and/or provide a bundle installer, as @IInspectable mentioned.